# Adding serial number to the table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code that displays data from the MySQL database. I would like to add a serial number for which I tried with the following code but it doesn't work as it's not in the loop and also it doesn't know endpoint and so I have max at 12:

```
<?php foreach (range(0, 12) as $number) { echo $number; }?>
```

Here's the main PHP code. How do I add a serial number to the `<td>` block:

```
<tbody>
        <?php foreach ($items as $i => $item) : ?>
            <tr id="tablelist_item_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="<?php echo $fc_item_classes.' row'.($i%2 ? 1 : 0); ?>" <?php echo $microdata_itemtype_code; ?>>
            
            <?php if ( $buttons_exists || $show_title || count($item->css_markups) ) : ?>
              <td><?php foreach (range(0, 12) as $number) { echo $number; }?></td>
                <td class="fc_title_col">
                
                <?php if ($show_title) : ?>
                    <!-- BOF item title -->
                    <span class="fc_item_title" itemprop="name">
                    <?php if ($link_titles) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(FlexicontentHelperRoute::getItemRoute($item->slug, $item->categoryslug, 0, $item)); ?>" itemprop="url"><?php echo $item->title; ?></a>
                <?php else : ?>
                        <?php echo $item->title; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </span>
                    <!-- EOF item title -->
                <?php endif; ?>
                
                <div class="fcclear fc_beforemarkups"></div>
                
                </td>
            <?php endif; ?>
        
        
            <!-- BOF item fields -->
            <?php foreach ($columns as $name => $label) : ?>
                <td><?php echo isset($item->positions['table']->{$name}->display) ? $item->positions['table']->{$name}->display : ''; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <!-- EOF item fields -->
                    
            </tr>
    
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: add row_number to your query it is a window function in mysql 8 and mariadb or as user defined variable in prior versions

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this: `<td><?php echo ($i+1); ?></td>`

and it works :)